# Inner Functions in Annuli: Not Likely!

Tags: complex-analysis, reference-request, proof-verification, hardy-spaces

The other day someone reminded me of something I'd thought about some years ago. As back then it took me a little while to see why there was any problem; this time I got much farther on a solution than I did back then.

This is supposed to be a question. Question: Is the stuff below (especially the result at the very end) actually true? Question: Reference?

**Background**
If $\Omega\subset\Bbb C$ is open the notation $H^\infty(\Omega)$ denotes the bounded holomorphic functions in $\Omega$. If $\Bbb D$ is the unit disk it's very well known that $f\in H^\infty(\Bbb D)$ has radial limits, in fact "non-tangential" limits, at almost every boundary point. A function $f\in H^\infty(\Bbb D)$ is an *inner function* if the boundary values have modulus $1$ almost everywhere. If $f\in H^\infty(\Bbb D)$ and the zeroes of $f$ are $(a_j)$ then $$\sum(1-|a_j|)<\infty.$$Conversely, this condition implies that $(a_j)$ is the zero set of some inner function (a Blaschke product).

**The Problem**

Now fix $R\in(0,1)$ and let $A$ be the annulus $R<|z|<1$. Define "inner function" in the obvious way. What are the zero sets of the inner functions in $A$?

**Obvious Conjecture (OC)**

The obvious conjecture is that $(a_j)$ is the zero set of an inner function in $A$ if and only if $$\sum d(a_j,\partial A)<\infty.$$Seems like an obvious conjecture to me anyway. The zero set of any (non-trivial) $f\in H^\infty(A)$ satisfies this  condition; this follows in any of various ways from the result in the disk.

Conversely, given $(a_j)$ with $\sum d(a_j,\partial A)<\infty$, separate the $a_j$ into two classes, those closer to $|z|=1$ and those closer to $|z|=R$. Let $B_1$ be the Blachke product formed from the $a_j$ in the first class, and let $B_2$ be the Blaschke product with zeroes at $R/a_j$ for $a_j$ in the second class. Let $$f(z)=B_1(z)B_2(R/z).$$For minute I thought that was an inner function. Of course it's not. But it *is* a bounded holomorphic function, so we've established this:

**Theorem** The sequence $(a_j)$ is the zero set of some $f\in H^\infty(A)$ if and only if $\sum d(a_j,\partial A)<\infty$.

To get an inner function with the right zero set I thought I'd try constructing some things analogous to Blaschke products. So given $a\in A$ I want to construct or say something about an inner function with just one zero, at $a$; then I could hope that a product of such things converged.

Getting an inner function with zero set $\{a\}$ is very simple. Just say $$f(z)=(z-a)e^{u(z)+iv(z)},$$where $u$ is the solution to the Dirichlet problem with boundary data $-\log|z-a|$ and $v$ is a harmonic conjugate of $u$. For a few hours some years ago and a few hours the other day I thought that did it. **Oops**, harmonic functions need not have harmonic conjugates. Too much time in the disk...

So this raises the question of which harmonic functions in $A$ have harmonic conjugates. And then come to think of it, $e^{u+iv}$ can be single-valued even if $v$ is not; the actual question of interest is which harmonic functions in $A$ are equal to $\log|f|$ for some non-vanishing holomorphic function $f$. I was surprised that both these questions have simple answers.

In general let $u^\#$ be the *radialization* or *radial part* of $u$: $$u^\#(z)=\frac1{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}u(e^{it}z)\,dt.$$

**Calculus** $$r\frac d{dr}u^\#(r)=\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}2\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}\,dz.$$(Express $\partial u/\partial z$ in polar coordinates...)

Now note that if $u$ is harmonic in $A$ then there exist $a,b\in\Bbb R$ with $$u^\#(r)=a+b\log(r).$$We will say $b(u)=b$ below.

**Theorem** Suppose $u$ is harmonic in $A$. (i) The function $u$ has a harmonic conjugate if and only if $b(u)=0$. (ii) There exists a nonvanishing holomorphic $f$ with $u=\log|f|$ if and only if $b(u)\in\Bbb Z$.

Proof (i) One direction is just Cauchy's Theorem. For the other direction, suppose $b(u)=0$. Note that $\partial u/\partial z$ is holomorphic. The calculus above shows that $\int_\gamma\partial u/\partial z=0$ for any closed curve $\gamma$. Hence $\partial u/\partial z$ has an antiderivative: There exists a holomorphic $f$ with $2\partial u/\partial z=f'=\partial f/\partial z$. This says that $2u-\overline f$ is holomorphic. Hence $2u-(\overline f+f)$ is holomorphic and real-valued, hence constant.

(ii) Suppose that $u=\log|f|$. Then $2\partial u/\partial z=f'/f$. Since $\frac1{2\pi i}\int_{|z|=r}f'/f\in\Bbb Z$ the calculus above shows that $u^\#=c+n\log(r)$, $n\in\Bbb Z$. Conversely, suppose $b(u)=n\in\Bbb Z$. Let $v(z)=u(z)-n\log|z|$. Part (i) shows that $v$ has a harmonic conjugate $w$, and hence $v=\log\left|e^{v+iw}\right|$. So $u=\log\left|z^ne^{v+iw}\right|$. QED.

We can now determine which finite subsets of $A$ are the zero sets of inner functions. Given $a_1,\dots,a_n\in A$, let $$p(z)=\prod_{j=1}^n(z-a_j),$$and let $u$ be the solution to the Dirichlet problem with boundary data $-\log|p|$. There exists an inner function with zero set the same as $p$ if and only if there exists $f$ with $u=\log|f|$. This happens if and only if $b(u)\in\Bbb Z$. One can calulate $u^\#(1)$ and $u^\#(R)$ explicitly, and it turns out that

**Theorem** Suppose $a_1,\dots,a_n\in A$. There exists an inner function with precisely these zeroes if and only if $$\frac1{\log(R)}\sum_{j=1}^n\log|a_j|\in\Bbb Z.\quad(*)$$That seems interesting enough to justify reading this far, not that anybody will.

**Corollary** Inner functions are not as fundamental in $A$ as they are in $\Bbb D$.

**Corollary** $n=1$ is impossible: There is no inner function in $A$ with exactly one zero.

But $n=2$ is possible. Very curious.

That's as far as I got way back then. What about inner functions with infinitely many zeroes? Condition ($*$) makes no sense.

Say $R<R'<1$. An analysis like the above, with that $B_1(z)B_2(R/z)$ thing in place of $p$, proves this:

**Theorem**. Suppose $a_1,\dots\in A$. There exists an inner function with zero set $(a_j)$ if and only if $\sum d(a_j,\partial A)<\infty$ and $$\frac1{\log(R)}\left(\sum_{|a_j|>R'}\log|a_j|-\sum_{|a_j|\le R'}\log\left|\frac{R}{a_j}\right|\right)\in\Bbb Z.$$I'll spare you the details. Heh.

Comment: As far as the second corollary to $(\ast)$ is concerned, if we restrict our attention to functions with $$\lim_{z\to \partial A} \lvert f(z)\rvert = 1,$$ we can reflect in a boundary circle [reflection shows that then $f$ extends continuously to the boundary]  and obtain an elliptic function on the torus obtained from factoring out $z\sim R^2z$. Letting $g(z) = f(e^z)$ we get the lattice form, and $(\ast)$ becomes the familiar fact that $\sum m_\nu\cdot z_\nu - \sum k_\mu\cdot p_\mu \in \Lambda$ for an elliptic function ...

Comment: ... (for the lattice $\Lambda$) with zeros $z_\nu$ of multiplicity $m_\nu$ and poles $p_\mu$ of multiplicity $k_\mu$. So for $(\ast)$ we always have an inner function that extends continuously to the boundary (and meromorphically past the boundary) with the prescribed zeros. Okay. But for infinitely many zeros, that of course breaks down.

Comment: Thanks. I'm going to put the word "familiar" in quotes - you have no idea what an ignorant guy you're dealing with here. Anyway, you have any idea whether the result for infinitely many zeroes is known?

Comment: No idea whether it's known. And I haven't checked the details, so I don't _know_ (yet) whether it's true, but I'm pretty confident that it is.

Comment: A natural source to consult is [Sarason's memoir of 1965](http://www.amazon.com/Annulus-Memoirs-American-Mathematical-Society/dp/B0007DZ36G); I don't have it handy at present.

Comment: Remark 1: Corollary 2 i.e. (*) for $n=2$, looks similar to [Rudin, p. 432, Example 1](http://www.ams.org/journals/tran/1969-140-00/S0002-9947-1969-0241629-0/S0002-9947-1969-0241629-0.pdf) (he has annulus $r<|z|<1/r$, that's why $|a_1a_2|=1$). Also somehow similar arguments on the last page of [this paper](http://arxiv.org/pdf/1201.5592v1.pdf) (some misprints though, $q$ should be $\log q$).

Comment: Remark 2: interesting to note that $\{b(u)\}$ is exactly the fundamental group. For a simply connected where a harmonic conjugate always exists the group is trivial, for an annulus it is $\cong(\mathbb{Z},+)$.

Comment: @A.G. Yes, it's interesting. One wonders what's going on in domains other than annuli. Of course then there's no $b(u)$, but one can talk about $\frac1{2\pi i}\int_\gamma f'/f$... Thanks for the references. Yes, $n=2$ looks a lot like that example in Rudin. (In fact if $(\log(r_1)+\log(r_2))/\log(R)$ is an integer it's clear it must equal $1$...)

Comment: @A.G. On second thought, I wonder whether that $\Bbb Z$ is "really" the fundamental group or something else. In domains other than annuli there are all sorts of things we can talk about analogous to things above: harmonic functions mod harmonic functions with harmonic conjugates, functions of the form $\log|f|$ mod harmonic functions with harmonic conjugates. etc. None of these are the fundamental group because they're all abelian. (If I weren't afraid of making a fool of myself through almost total ignorance of topology I'd conjecture that we're really talking about some sort of cohomology")

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich It was just a guess that it might be something more than a coincidence, but I have to admit that I do not have a strong argument for that, just a feeling. Perhaps it is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

For a general finitely connected domain (with reasonable boundary) a finite set of  points is the zero set of an inner function that is analytic across the boundary if and only if the sum of these points, under the Abel-Jacobi map, is pure imaginary modulo the period lattice. The result can be found in Fay's book on theta functions on Riemann surfaces. As a corollary, for a region with g holes, the minimum number of zeros of a non-constant inner function is g+1. The Schottky double of the region is a Riemann surface and the inner function reflects to a meromorphic function - so one expects constraints on the zeros and poles.